# Inno Setup - Pascal code visibility - "Unknown identifier" error

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I have a file in my installer with an `AfterInstall` action like so:

```
AfterInstall: UpdateImageLoaderConfigValues()
```

And I would like the procedure to call the same Pascal Script function twice as I can't have two `AfterInstall` actions as far as I am aware, so I have set this up like so:

```pascal
procedure UpdateImageLoaderConfigValues();
begin
  SaveValueToXML(ExpandConstant('{app}\ImageLoader.exe.config'),{#ImageLoaderLastConfigurationPath}, ExpandConstant('{app}/Configurations'))
  SaveValueToXML(ExpandConstant('{app}\ImageLoader.exe.config'),{#ImageLoaderLastImagePath}, ExpandConstant('{app}/Images'))
end;
```

And my function `SaveValueToXML` has a signature:

```pascal
function SaveValueToXML(const AFileName, APath, AValue: string);
```

The problem is that compilation fails because of

> Unknown identifier 'SaveValueToXML'

error at the points in `UpdateImageLoaderConfigValues` where I am trying to use this function.

How can I make `SaveValueToXML` visible to `UpdateImageLoaderConfigValues`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define the `SaveValueToXML` before the `UpdateImageLoaderConfigValues`:

```pascal
[Files]
Source: ...; AfterInstall: UpdateImageLoaderConfigValues()

[Code]

function SaveValueToXML(const AFileName, APath, AValue: string);
begin
  { ... }
end;

procedure UpdateImageLoaderConfigValues();
begin
  SaveValueToXML(ExpandConstant('{app}\ImageLoader.exe.config'),{#ImageLoaderLastConfigurationPath}, ExpandConstant('{app}/Configurations'))
  SaveValueToXML(ExpandConstant('{app}\ImageLoader.exe.config'),{#ImageLoaderLastImagePath}, ExpandConstant('{app}/Images'))
end;
```

---

*For others, who arrive here with the same error message, but on a variable identifier, rather than on a `function` or `procedure` call, , see [Inno Setup Pascal script problem... "Unknown Identifier"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55064157/850848)*.