# Inno Setup Pascal script problem... "Unknown Identifier"

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I'm trying to check if java 8 is in registry or java 9-11 are in registry, so i make this script:

```
[Code]
{ Script to check if a JRE is installed, it will search for the old java 8 location and for the new java 11 location }  
function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
var
  ErrorCode: Integer;
  JavaVer: string;
begin
    { checking for old java 8 location }  
    RegQueryStringValue(
        HKLM64, 'SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment', 'CurrentVersion', JavaVer);
    ResultOldJava := (Length(JavaVer) > 0);

    { checking for new java 9-11 location }  
    RegQueryStringValue(
        HKLM64, 'SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\JDK', 'CurrentVersion', JavaVer);
    ResultNewJava := (Length(JavaVer) > 0);

    if not ResultOldJava and not ResultNewJava then
    begin
        if MsgBox('ATENCIÓN: Gestor requiere Java 64 Bits instalado en el sistema. No se ha encontrado, ¿Desea abrir la página de descargas oficial? Por favor, recuerde que es necesaria la versión de 64 bits.', mbConfirmation, MB_YESNO) = idYes then
        begin
            ShellExec(
              'open', 'https://www.java.com/es/download/manual.jsp#win',
              '', '', SW_SHOWNORMAL, ewNoWait, ErrorCode);
        end;
    end;
end;
```

The problem is that it's printing this error:

```
Unknown Identifier 'ResultOldJava'
```

What is wrong? my skills in pascal are very low

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declare the `ResultOldJava` variable, the same way you already declare `ErrorCode` and `JavaVer`:

```pascal
function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
var
  ErrorCode: Integer;
  JavaVer: string;
  ResultOldJava: Boolean; 
begin
```

---

*For others, who arrive here with the same error message, but on a `function` or `procedure` call, rather than on a variable identifier, see [Inno Setup - Pascal code visibility - "Unknown identifier" error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36567129/850848)*.